# Why adding items to an invisible element set these to be invisible in the "style" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery and jscrollpane to display some data with a custom scroll.

The problem I am facing is that while the user is browsing the website I append items to an UL and when the user hits a button these are supposed to be shown. The problem is that these elements as they were being appended to a placeholder div with "display:none", something in either jquery or jscrollpane sets their style attribute to a width of 0 thus making them invisible.

Do any of you know what is causing this?

Comment: Invisible elements don't have any height or width -- it can't be computed until they're made visible.

Comment: even if I set their height and width through css? or while appending them?

Comment: Please show the code you're using. `.css()` should return the width attribute you assigned, but `.width()` should return the calculated width, which isn't available when it's invisible.

Comment: @barmar [How is that](http://jsfiddle.net/fLUFy/)?

Comment: Put your code in the question.

Comment: @MaG3Stican Your basic problem is, that when you set "placeholder div" visible again, you can't see the appended elements? Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `display: none` makes the element have no impact on the page.

Instead, try using `visibility: hidden`, this makes it only disappear while still keeping its height and width.